# How to open an Excel file in a specific path for any user?

Tags: python

Goodafternoon,

Im opening an Excel file using Python:

```
absolutePath = Path('C:\\Users\\jimmy\\Downloads\\Demo.csv').resolve()
os.system(f'start excel.exe "{absolutePath}"')
```

Sadly this only works for me, because my username is jimmy, for my colleague it doesn't work under his username.

How can I use this code on other computers with other usernames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the username of the currently logged in user via os and then put that into the path string

```
import os
username = os.getenv("username")

absolutePath = Path(f'C:\\Users\\{username}\\Downloads\\Demo.csv').resolve()
os.system(f'start excel.exe "{absolutePath}"')
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfect @Sidney!

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths to your python script:

```
import os
current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path_csv = os.path.join(current_dir, "Demo.csv")

absolutePath = Path(path_csv).resolve()
os.system(f'start excel.exe "{absolutePath}"')
```

Then place your python script in the same directory than your csv file.

Comment: Also good solution, but Sidney's solution worked out a little bit better for my current situation! Thanks!